# click submit button but cannot found page

Tags: codeigniter

I want to make calculate the area of square, but when I click the submit button, page cannot be found :

**controller :**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Controller_luas extends CI_Controller {

public function coba_controller($panjang=0,$lebar=0){
    $nilai['panjang_bangunan'] = $panjang;
    $nilai['lebar_bangunan'] = $lebar;
    $nilai['luas_bangunan'] = $this->mymodel->hitungluas($nilai);
    $this->load->view('coba_view',$nilai);
}
}
```

**view :**

```
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/controller_luas/"; ?>">
    <table widht="200" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Panjang</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="cari_judul"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lebar</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="cari_penulis"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Hasil"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h1>Luas Perseginya yaitu : <?php echo $luas_bangunan ?><h1>
    </form>
```

**models :**

```
function hitungluas($param=''){
    $luas=$param['panjang_bangunan'] * $param['lebar_bangunan'];
    return $luas;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you give right filename to your controller file. ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are submitting to the controller Controller_luas

It is submitting to the index function even though I do not see it there.

If you need it to go to **coba_controller function** then in form action you need to add it.

With index.php

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/controller_luas/coba_controller'); ?>">
```

Without index.php

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('controller_luas/coba_controller'); ?>">
```

Using Codeigniter Form Helper

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Or you can auto load this

```
$this->load->helper('form');

<?php echo form_open('controller_luas/coba_controller');?>
// Form Content
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

You also might be best to use codeigniter form validation library as well.